# use django "include" inside a js function

Tags: python, django, ajax

I am doing a search page in which parameters are sent by ajax and then upon reception of the queryset I rebuild my cards. The whole thing is classic and working ok, here is a simplified version of the thing. Lots of lines killed or modified since it is not really the subject of the post

```
let getobject = async (value,url) => {
    var res2 = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"),
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            value: value,
        })
    })
    let data2 = await res2.json();
    videoitems.innerHTML = ''
    modalbin.innerHTML = ''
    data2["data"].forEach(async item => {
        if (item.ext == '.mp4') {
            const dynamicreation = async () => {
                let dyncontent3 = await createnewcard(item)
                let placing = await videoitems.appendChild(dyncontent3);
            }
            const nooncares2 = await dynamicreation()
        } else if (item.ext == ".pdf") {
            const dynamicreation2 = async () => {
                let dyncontent4 = await createnewcard(item)
                let placing2 = await videoitems.appendChild(dyncontent4);
            }
            const nooncares4 = dynamicreation2()
        }
    })
}
```

the createnewcard function

```
var createnewcard = item => {
    var dyncontent =  document.createElement("div");
      dyncontent.innerHTML = 
      `<div class="m-2 extralarge-modal video${item.id}">
        <div data-reco="${item.id}"
          class="extralarge-modal  bg-white rounded-lg border border-gray-200 shadow-md dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
          <div class="p-5">
            <p class="mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
              ${item.title}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>`;
      return dyncontent
    }
```

What I would like to know is if it would be possible to mix this js with the django "include" function and instead of using js template litterals use an html component of the card that I would include upon looping in the data reveived. I could also maybe include it inside the createnewcard js function but so far it all failed quite miserably.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you've to create **`card.html`** or whatever you can name then you've to just include inside your js make sure you use same variables while looping in js eg.(`item`)

**card.html**

```
<div class="m-2 extralarge-modal video${item.id}">
  <div data-reco="${item.id}"
          class="extralarge-modal  bg-white rounded-lg border border-gray-200 shadow-md dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
    <div class="p-5">
       <p class="mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
          ${item.title}
       </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

and inside your **Js** do like this

```
var createnewcard = item => {
    var dyncontent =  document.createElement("div");
    dyncontent.innerHTML = `{% include "card.html" %}`
    return dyncontent
}
```

---

Comment: Thanks Ankit, it worked with adding the template litteral backticks to  x {% include "card.html" %} x  (replace the x with template litteral since we cannot use them in a stackoverflow textbox)